# Interactive image (map)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to make an interactive image for my web page so the A, B, C, ... N points will pop up when clicking on them and reveal a bubble with an image and some writing in it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErRo2.png)

Can someone please tell me how to do it? Or where can I fint the information I need?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)! You need to try to write the code **yourself**. After doing [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and you still have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of **what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: The easiest way to do this, in my opinion, is to try to get the image _without_ the nodes, then create the nodes yourself and position them like they were before.  Then, use some CSS transitions and `@keyframes` animations.

Answer (score 2):

### Creating the image map

As suggested by [Badacadabra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6910253/badacadabra), you can use Gimp to create an image map, but I also like this online tool: [image-maps.com](http://www.image-maps.com)

Give your `<area>`'s an ID, or something that will allow you to identify them:

```
<img id="myImage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErRo2.png" usemap="#myMap" alt="" />
<map name="myMap" id="myMap">
    <area id="node-a" shape="rect" coords="731,159,757,188"/>
    <area id="node-b" shape="rect" coords="685,139,713,168"/>
    <area id="node-c" shape="rect" coords="597,142,625,171"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</map>
```

### Making it responsive

The problem with image maps is that they are not responsive. Since we're not in 2005 anymore, we'll use a plugin to make sure this works well on all screen sizes. This one is nice: [Image Map Resizer by David Bradshaw](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer). We can enable it like this:

```
imageMapResize();
```

### Formatting your data

To assign content to each node, you could use an Object:

```
var myData = {
    "node-a": {
        "title": "This point A",
        "image": "image-a.jpg",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum A dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-b": {
        "title": "This point B",
        "image": "image-B.jpg",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet."
    },
    /* ... */
};
```

### Creating your popup

If you're not too comfortable with creating your own popups, there are plenty of plugins out there. For this demo, we'll create one of our own (basically an absolutely positioned div we can toggle):

```
<div id="myBubble">
  <div id="myBubbleContent"></div>
  <div id="myBubbleCloseButton">✕</div>
</div>
```

Add some styling to it, and make it work with JS:

```
// References to DOM elements
var areas         = document.getElementsByTagName('area'),
    bubble        = document.getElementById('myBubble'),
    bubbleContent = document.getElementById('myBubbleContent'),
    bubbleClose   = document.getElementById('myBubbleCloseButton');

// On click of an area, open popup
for(var i=0, l=areas.length; i<l; i++) {
  areas[i].addEventListener('click', openBubble, false);
}

// On click of close button, close popup
bubbleClose.addEventListener('click', closeBubble, false);

function openBubble() {
  var content = myData[this.id];
  bubbleContent.innerHTML = '<h3>' + content.title + '</h3>'
                          + '<img src="' + content.image + '" alt="" />'
                          + '<p>' + content.description + '</p>';
  bubble.className = 'shown';
}

function closeBubble() {
  bubble.className = '';
}
```

### Full demo

Try it by expanding the snippet below:

```js
var myData = {
    "node-a": {
        "title": "This point A",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=A&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum A dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-b": {
        "title": "This point B",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=B&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum B dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-c": {
        "title": "This point C",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=C&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum C dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-d": {
        "title": "This point D",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=D&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum D dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-e": {
        "title": "This point E",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=E&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum E dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-f": {
        "title": "This point F",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=F&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum F dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-g": {
        "title": "This point G",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=G&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum G dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-h": {
        "title": "This point H",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=H&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum H dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-i": {
        "title": "This point I",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=I&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum I dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-j": {
        "title": "This point J",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=J&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum J dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-k": {
        "title": "This point K",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=K&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum K dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-l": {
        "title": "This point L",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=L&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum L dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-m": {
        "title": "This point M",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=M&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum M dolor sin amet."
    },
    "node-n": {
        "title": "This point N",
        "image": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=70&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=N&w=300&h=110&txttrack=0",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum N dolor sin amet."
    }
};

// References to DOM elements
var areas         = document.getElementsByTagName('area'),
    bubble        = document.getElementById('myBubble'),
    bubbleContent = document.getElementById('myBubbleContent'),
    bubbleClose   = document.getElementById('myBubbleCloseButton');

// On click of an area, open popup
for(var i=0, l=areas.length; i<l; i++) {
  areas[i].addEventListener('click', openBubble, false);
}

// On click of close button, close popup
bubbleClose.addEventListener('click', closeBubble, false);

function openBubble() {
  var content = myData[this.id];
  bubbleContent.innerHTML = '<h3>' + content.title + '</h3>'
                          + '<img src="' + content.image + '" alt="" />'
                          + '<p>' + content.description + '</p>';
  bubble.className = 'shown';
}

function closeBubble() {
  bubble.className = '';
}

// Make the image map responsive
imageMapResize();
```

```css
#myWrapper{ position: relative; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#myImage{ display: block; width: 100%; }
#myBubble{ position: absolute; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #aaa; padding: .5rem 1rem; display: none; top: 1.5rem; left: 1.5rem; width: 15rem; }
#myBubble.shown{ display: block; }
#myBubble img{ display: block; width: 100%; }
#myBubbleCloseButton{ position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; padding: .5rem; background: #eee; line-height: 1; cursor: pointer; }
#myBubbleCloseButton:hover{ background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<!-- Image Map Resizer plugin -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer/master/js/imageMapResizer.js"></script>

<div id="myWrapper">
    <img id="myImage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErRo2.png" usemap="#myMap" alt="" />
    <map name="myMap" id="myMap">
        <area id="node-a" shape="rect" coords="731,159,757,188"/>
        <area id="node-b" shape="rect" coords="685,139,713,168"/>
        <area id="node-c" shape="rect" coords="597,142,625,171"/>
        <area id="node-d" shape="rect" coords="537,179,565,208"/>
        <area id="node-e" shape="rect" coords="523,206,551,235"/>
        <area id="node-f" shape="rect" coords="477,274,505,303"/>
        <area id="node-g" shape="rect" coords="385,292,413,321"/>
        <area id="node-h" shape="rect" coords="335,282,363,311"/>
        <area id="node-i" shape="rect" coords="285,292,313,321"/>
        <area id="node-j" shape="rect" coords="249,312,277,341"/>
        <area id="node-k" shape="rect" coords="228,324,256,353"/>
        <area id="node-l" shape="rect" coords="205,335,233,364"/>
        <area id="node-m" shape="rect" coords="155,363,183,392"/>
        <area id="node-n" shape="rect" coords="29,428,57,457"/>
    </map>
    <div id="myBubble">
      <div id="myBubbleContent"></div>
      <div id="myBubbleCloseButton">✕</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GIMP** to generate your map element...

Here is a minimal working example without JavaScript (HTML only):

```html
<map name="map">
  <area shape="circle" coords="46,441,12" title="N">
  <area shape="circle" coords="168,374,11" title="M">
  <area shape="circle" coords="217,347,11" title="L">
  <area shape="circle" coords="238,339,10" title="K">
  <area shape="circle" coords="260,323,11" title="J">
  <area shape="circle" coords="299,306,10" title="I">
  <area shape="circle" coords="348,296,12" title="H">
  <area shape="circle" coords="399,308,12" title="G">
  <area shape="circle" coords="490,286,10" title="F">
  <area shape="circle" coords="537,220,12" title="E">
  <area shape="circle" coords="550,195,10" title="D">
  <area shape="circle" coords="610,156,10" title="C">
  <area shape="circle" coords="699,152,11" title="B">
  <area shape="circle" coords="745,174,11" title="A">
</map>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErRo2.png" usemap="#map">
```